# Get data from two connected table with php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have two connected tables - `days` and `user_days`:

DAYS:
[image]

USER_DAYS:
[image]

How I need to check if there is today (unix_date) record in user_days with user_id, and if yes then I need to get day_id after that to get data from table DAYS with day_id as ID...

I write:

```
 public function getDay($user_id) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT d.id, d.day, d.status, d.created_at, d.dayDate from days d, user_days ud WHERE d.id = ? AND ud.dayDate = d.dayDate AND ud.user_id = ?");
        $t=time();
        $dayDate = date("Y-m-d",$t);
        $stmt->bind_param("si", $dayDate, $user_id);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $res = array();
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $day, $status, $created_at, $dayDate);
            // TODO
            // $task = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->fetch();
            $res["id"] = $id;
            $res["task"] = $task;
            $res["status"] = $status;
            $res["created_at"] = $created_at;
            $res["dayDate"] = $dayDate;
            $stmt->close();
            return $res;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
```

}

on other side as index.php I have less important code:

```
$app->get('/days', 'authenticate', function() {
            global $user_id;
            $response = array();
            $db = new DbHandler();

            // fetch task
            $result = $db->getDay($user_id);

            if ($result != NULL) {
                $response["error"] = false;
                $response["id"] = $result["id"];
                $response["day"] = $result["day"];
                $response["status"] = $result["status"];
                $response["createdAt"] = $result["created_at"];
                $response["dayDate"] = $result["dayDate"];
                echoRespnse(200, $response);
            } else {
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["message"] = "The requested resource doesn't exists";
                echoRespnse(404, $response);
            }
        });
```

I just get this output which is not correct:

```
 Object {error: false, id: 0, day: null, status: 0, createdAt: null}
```

What is wrong with my QUERY, I think that QUERY is problem but I can solve it by hours...

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html is your friend...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In getday(), I think you should replace `$res["task"] = $task;` with `$res["day"]=$day`.

Comment: ok, but that wasnt problem: I solve this with changing QUERY: WHERE d.dayDate= ? AND ud.dayDate = d.dayDate AND ud.user_id = ?");